# Join query with condition by second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables one is users and second is locations
locations are one to many relationship with users.
I want to list all users based on latest location with condition distance(km) > 0.01. Please anyone?

I tried .syntax error (Query 1 ERROR: Unknown column 'd' in 'where clause')

```
SELECT *, (SELECT distance 
           from locations 
           where locations.user_id = users.id 
           order by created_at DESC 
           LIMIT 1
          ) as d 
from users 
where d > 0.01
```

Edit

tables 
- users
- locations(multiple) (id,user_id,lat,lng,distance,created_at)

Expected result
- list of users(not duplicate) where latest locations contain distance less then 0.1 (double distance)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  How is distance calculated?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Distance auto calculated while inserting. in double

Comment: Should we guess? MySQL does not return a laconic "syntax error". The returned error usually has a useful hint and the error number is described in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: Yes, Query 1 ERROR: Unknown column 'd' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derived column `d` is not allowed in the `WHERE` clause but you could use a `HAVING` clause:

```
having d > 0.01
```

Another way to get the results that you want, if you can't use window functions, is the join of your table to a query that uses `NOT EXISTS` to return the locations that you need:

```
select u.*, t.distance
from users u inner join ( 
  select l.* from locations l
  where not exists (select 1 from locations where user_id = l.user_id and created_at > l.created_at)
    and l.distance > 0.01 
) t on t.user_id = u.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function :

```
select t.*
from (select u.*, l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by u.id order by l.created_at desc) as seq
      from users u inner join
           locations l
           on l.user_id = u.id
     ) t
where seq = 1 and distance > 0.01;
```